# URLSession not following 302s on ios 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

When running my code on a device that's on iOS 13, I'm getting an error that I'm not seeing on any previous version of iOS. I'm getting:

> NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1007

My code is

```swift
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (_, res, _) in
 // Do stuff
}.resume()
```

The server responds with a 302 and resolves fine on the previous iOS versions (redirects once and resolves). On iOS 13 it keeps redirecting to the original URL until it says too many redirects. Is this a bug with iOS 13 or should I be doing something different?

Comment: You are supposed to discuss any issue for an unreleashed OS version at Apple's developer forums.

Comment: Thank you. I made a post here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/368858#368858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue fixed itself with XCode 11 Beta 3.